# Regex to find a specific word between quotes within MXML

Tags: regex

I found this regex somewhere online that finds strings in my files that are likely presented to the user for a localization clean-up. However, I have a new task to find specific instances of two words and I thought I could use the same regex. I have tried several combinations but I'm just not good enough at regex to get it right.

Current regex for finding strings:

```
(?<=text=|label=|prompt=|toolTip=|title=|icon=|String=|Error=|Separator=|Symbol=)(("(?:\.|(\\\")|[^\""\n])*")|('(?:\.|(\\\')|[^\''\n])*'))
```

But now I want it to also capture if the words: ***catalog*** or ***in stock*** exist anywhere between the quotes.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That regex doesn't really have anything to do with your current concern; I think it's just confusing things. At any rate, you should start that line with 4 spaces so it gets formatted as code. Much easier to read that way.

Comment: Are you looking for just "catalog" or "in stock", or do you want any case where those phrases appear between two quotation marks?

Comment: Not sure what you mean but I am pretty sure it does have something to do with it. The current expression looks for anything within single or double quotes that is also a part of one of those assignment statements. So I want to add to this rule that is must contain either "catalog" or "in stock" as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, this should do it, I believe:

```
(?<=text=|label=|prompt=|toolTip=|title=|icon=|String=|Error=|Separator=|Symbol=)((?:"(?:\.|(\\\")|[^\""\n])*\b(?:catalog|in stock)\b(?:\.|(\\\")|[^\""\n])*")|(?:'(?:\.|(\\\')|[^\''\n])*\b(?:catalog|in stock)\b(?:\.|(\\\')|[^\''\n])*'))
```

All I did was add `\b(?:catalog|in stock)\b` in the quote section. For example, for the double-quote section, it used to be this:

```
"(?:\.|(\\\")|[^\""\n])*"
```

I.e. any number of non-quote (unless escaped), non-return characters between double-quotes.

Now it is this:

```
"(?:\.|(\\\")|[^\""\n])*\b(?:catalog|in stock)\b(?:\.|(\\\")|[^\""\n])*"
```

Which is a double-quote, any number of legal characters as above, "catalog" or "in stock", any number of more legal characters, and a quote.